# What polynomial do I need for regression of such relations

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, polynomial

I have following 4 graphs and for each I have to do regression.

[image]

The relation is clearly curvilinear. What term should I use for regression (eg  y ~ x+x^2) for each of these?

Comment: They all look like they could be fitted with 4-point Bezier curves, so I would suggest a cubic polynomial will probably be sufficient.

Comment: In the graph on the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bezier_basis.svg  I could see B and D curves above but not A and C.

Comment: A(x) = k - D(x) for some constant k. Likewise C is a reflection of B in the x axis then translated.

Comment: What is the application by the way?

Comment: And those basis curves are to do with calculating the curve, not the output.

Comment: I wanted to put the x variable in a multiple regression model where y is the response variable and where there are other predictor variables also apart from x. I was thinking more in terms of log(x) and poly(x,5) or x^3 etc terms to put in regression model.

Comment: Right. Sorry I made a mistake - Bezier curves are cubic parametric curves, not cubic Cartesian, but looking I still think you will need at least an order 3 polynomial.

Comment: Or you could use exponentials of some kind, but that will be tricky because you'll need something of the form $a + b \exp(c + dx)$ to cover all bases

Comment: Sorry I'm not being very helpful! Is there a known physical relationship between x and y? Or constraints on x or y or their relationship? Also are these 4 different x variables or are they the same x variable with different y variables, or the same x and y but in different strata defined by a covariate?

Comment: I have to do 4 regressions. I have plotted x vs y scatterplots which show curvilinear relation as shown above. For each case what term should I use for x. These are 4 separate cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted a few points from curve A and fairly successfully fitted a quartic (degree 4) polynomial. Lower order didn't fit very well. I suspect it should fit the other curves equally well.

I suggest you try your regression with $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$ and $x^4$ terms, but bear in mind that the fit is only for the range you fit - it probably shouldn't be used for any extrapolation without an understanding of the physical processes (if any) underlying.

Good luck!

Comment: How can you get B and C with $x^2$ etc?

Comment: You let the regression take care of that, just include the powers of x as additional variables.

Comment: And make sure you have a constant term as well